# Convert string into key-value pairs in an object in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a string.

*Input*
**let s  = aaabccddd**

I want to convert this string to key-> value pairs in an obj.

*output*
**let obj  = {
a:3,
b:1,
c:2,
d:3
}**

I know how to make keys but confuse about the value please give a javascript solution thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the string and increment a counter in a seperate object for each character.

```js
function countOccurences(string) {
    const result = {};

    for (const character of string) {
        if (typeof result[character] === 'undefined') {
            result[character] = 0;
        }

        result[character]++;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(countOccurences('aaabccddd'));
//=> {a: 3, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to invoke the [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on the string and group the characters by their occurrences.

```js
const 
  str = "aaabccddd",
  res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    str,
    (r, s) => {
      r[s] ??= 0;
      r[s] += 1;
      return r;
    },
    {}
  );

console.log(res);
```

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
let s = 'aaabccddd';

let result = [...s].reduce((o, c) =>  {
  o[c] = (o[c] | 0) + 1;
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.match()` with RegExp to get the repeated occurrences of each character, map them toan array of `[character, occurrences]` pairs, and convert the list of pairs to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const fn = s => Object.fromEntries(s
  .match(/(.)\1*/g) // find all recuring matches
  .map(str => [str[0], str.length]) // create an array of [character, occurrences]
)

const s = 'aaabccddd'

const result = fn(s)

console.log(result)
```

Or use `String.matchAll()` with `Array.from()` to create the list of entries:

```js
const fn = s => Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(
    s.matchAll(/(.)\1*/g), // find all recuring matches
    ([{ length }, c]) => [c, length] // create an array of [character, occurrences]
  ) 
)

const s = 'aaabccddd'

const result = fn(s)

console.log(result)
```